# laravel wherehas не работает

Tags: php, laravel

Есть простой запрос

```
\App\Models\User::whereHas('emails', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('emails.name', '=', 'adell17@gmail.com');
        })->get();
```

На который я должен получить юзеров, у которых указанная почта. Но я не получаю ничего... Может я не правильно как то пользуюсь whereHas?

Answer (score 1):

Если поле **name** принадлежать **emails**, то нужно обращаться напрямую

```
\App\Models\User::whereHas('emails', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('name', '=', 'adell17@gmail.com');
        })->get();
```

иди вы забили указать связи, в **hasMany** и **belongsTo**

Comment: нет, это никак не влияет, связи все belongsToMany

Comment: Ем, так belongsToMany это ManyToMany у вас в одного пользователя может быть несколько емайлов и в одного емайла может быть несколько пользователей? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: именно так, это внутренние почтовые ящики, распределяемые между менеджерами, и чтобы перераспределять потоки писем они могут дублироваться)))

Comment: Не могли бы вы в вопрос добавить код, как вяжутся даны через belongsToMany, в моделях